# Question regarding mysql_insert_id() application in my code

Tags: php, logic, if-statement, mysql-insert-id

I have a page in which there is an `if...else` loop for processing of input data, this page is reverted two times when submitted, that is when a button called "Continue" is clicked and and second time "Add to cart".... Now in this case when Button "Continue" is clicked then the `if` loop is executed in which data is inserted in the Database, and as the refreshes I get the display of all the input data and this time another button "Add to cart" is obtained.. when Add to cart is clicked the code included in the `else` condition/loop part is executed..

Now here my question is as if the data is initially inserted in `If`part and then later `else` is executed, so can i use the function `mysql_insert_id()` in else part to fetch the data last inserted in the `if` part?

Below is the type of code I am talking about:

```
If(Button Continue is clicked)
{
  insert query for a product table......
}
else Button Add to Cart is Clicked
{
  mysql_insert_id(); to fetch last id inserted in the above above loop/condition.. 
}
```

So can get the last inserted id in `else` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your scenario, then no. `mysql_insert_id` (and its mySQL cousin [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)) will return the last insert ID valid *for the current connection only*. That means that if you switch to the next page, a new connection will be established and `insert_id()` won't work.

A workaround may be putting the insert ID into a session variable right after making the query - it will be available in the other pages then. (Just be careful when a user has multiple tabs/windows open and makes two bookings at once - make sure you use some kind of identifier for each booking process.)

Answer (score 1):

> so can get the last inserted id in else part?

You can't. The only place you should be trying to retrieve the insert_id is just after performing the INSERT. You should never store transaction specific data in the session - so if you have multiple insert ids and need to pass this information between different pages then the records should reference a single 'master' record (e.g. shopping basket) since this does not change in its lifetime it would be safe to store the identifier for **this** record in the session.

C.